# Determinant inequality positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, determinant, positive-definite

If $A$ and $B$ are two positive definite matrices such that:
$$A \geq B,$$
can I conclude that:
$$\mathrm{det}(A) \geq \mathrm{det}(B).$$
(With the notation $A \geq B$, I mean that $A - B \geq 0$, i.e. $A-B$ is positive semi-definite).

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $A$ and $B$ are linear transformations on finite-dimensional inner product vector space, and if $0 \le A \le B$, then $det A \le det B$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3515308/if-a-and-b-are-linear-transformations-on-finite-dimensional-inner-product-ve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. $A\ge B$ is equivalent to $B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}A\ge I$. So, it implies that all eigenvalues of $B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}A$ are $\ge1$. It follows that $\det(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}A)\ge1$ and $\det(A)\ge\det(B)$.

Actually, by using the variational characterisation of eigenvalues of Hermitian matrices, it can be shown that $\lambda_i(A)\ge\lambda_i(B)$ when $A\ge B$. From this, we may also infer that $\det(A)\ge\det(B)$ when $B\ge0$.

Comment: Just to elaborate slightly, if the eigenvalues of $A$ are ordered $\lambda_1 \ge ...$ then $\lambda_k = \min_{\dim S = n=k+1} \max_{\|x\|=1, x \in S} x^* Ax$. It follows that $\lambda_k(A) \ge \lambda_k(B)$.