# When are the zeros of $x^T A x$ equal to kernel of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am wondering when the set of solutions to $x^T Ax = 0$ is equal to the kernel of the matrix $A$. Is there a general answer to this?

It seems to be true in the positive-definite case:

If $x^TAx = 0$ then $x$ must be $0$ (otherwise $x^TAx > 0$), so $Ax = 0$.
On the other hand, if $Ax = 0$ then $x^T Ax = x^T(Ax) = x^T \cdot 0 = 0$.

Similarly for the negative-definite case.

Comment: For symmetric matrices, it holds if and only if the matrix is either positive semidefinite or negative semidefinite. For some proofs for the "if" direction, see my post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3722044/81360).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a symmetric semi-definite matrix it still holds, as you see from diagonalising the matrix. But even for $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ it is no longer true.