# Positive and positive semi-definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Let $H_n$ be a $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ real symmetric matrix, and let $D_0,D_1,\dots, D_n$ be the leading principal minors of $H_n$.

What I know is:

1. If $H_n$ is positive definite (resp. positive semi definite), then $D_n> 0$ (resp. $D_n\geq 0$).
2. If $D_k>0$ for all $0\leq k\leq n$, then $H_n$ is positive definite (by [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion)).

What I want to know is, assuming that $H_n$ is positive semi-definite,

$\quad$ Q1. If $D_n>0$, then $H_n$ is positive definite.

$\quad$ Q2. If $H_n$ is not positive definite, then $D_n=0$.

For Q1: I believe it's done by induction over $n$. For $n=0$: If $D_0>0$, then $H_0$ is positive definite, by second point. For $n=1$: If $D_1>0$, how do you know that $D_0\neq 0$, so that we can use second point again?

For Q2: We know that $H_n$ is positive semi-definite by assumption, so $D_n\geq 0$ by first point. But, since $H_n$ is not positive semi-definite, we can't have $D_n>0$, so $D_n=0$. Is that it?

Comment: The answer to both questions is yes. In other words, a positive semidefinite matrix is positive definite if and only if it is invertible (has non-zero determinant).

Comment: @BenGrossmann Wow, that's an useful info you gave me there. Could you please inform me where you got this from? I'd love to know the proof of "if"-part.

Comment: It's a pretty standard fact, normally taken as a consequence of the following: a symmetric matrix is positive definite if and only if its eigenvalues are real and positive semidefinite if and only if its eigenvalues are non-negative. From there, the determinant of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues

Comment: For a more direct proof, it suffices to note that for a (symmetric) positive semidefinite matrix $H$, we have $x^THx = 0 \iff Hx = 0$. In my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3722044/81360), I prove this in a few different ways. From there, note that a matrix has zero determinant if and only if its nullspace (AKA kernel) is non-trivial)

Comment: It is settled, thank you. If you can write your two first comments in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A positive semidefinite matrix is positive definite if and only if it is invertible (has non-zero determinant).

This is normally taken as a consequence of the following: a symmetric matrix is positive definite if and only if its eigenvalues are real and positive semidefinite if and only if its eigenvalues are non-negative. From there, we note that the determinant of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues.

For a more direct proof, it suffices to note that for a (symmetric) positive semidefinite matrix $H$, we have $x^THx = 0 \iff Hx = 0$. In [my post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3722044/81360), I prove this in a few different ways. From there, note that a matrix has zero determinant if and only if its nullspace (AKA kernel) is non-trivial.