# A non-negative matrix $A$ has an inverse if and only if $A>0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, nonnegative-matrices

I know that $\mid A\mid$ cannot be zero.

If $A$ is non-negative, then $x^{T}Ax\geq 0$. $A$ being positive is equivalent to having all its corners as positive. The largest corner $A$ can have is $A$ itself, so therefore $\mid A\mid$ must be positive too. Does it then follow that it a non negative matrix cannot have an inverse $A^{-1}$, because it would break multiplying determinants?

I am pretty lost here, help needed if possible.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "all its corners positive"? What is a "corner" of a matrix? Also, what is $|A|$? Does that refer to the determinant of $A$?

Comment: In any case, one approach to this question is to note that if $A$ is non-negative, then $x^TAx = 0 \implies Ax = 0$. I give a few proofs of this fact in [my post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3722044/81360).