# Example for singular positive semi definite matrix with positive diagonal and its generalized inverse has $0$ first element

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, pseudoinverse

I need to find a counter example that satisfies the following:
1- the matrix $A_{n*n}, n>2$ symmetric and positive semidefinite, and the main diagonal is positive $a_{ii}>0$
2- the matrix $A$ is singular 
3- let $G$ be the generalized inverse of the matrix $A$. The $g_{11}=0$

is there a counter example of a matrix that satisfies all these conditions together?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134707/discussion-on-question-by-hanan-example-for-singular-positive-semi-definite-matr).

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks for all the replies. It seems that it will be only valid when $h=0$ because otherwise, the big matrix $A$ won't be singular, right? if true then can I say that $g_11^{+}\neq 0$ if at least $a_{ii}\neq 0$

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is a positive semidefinite matrix and $G$ is its pseudoinverse, then $g_{11} = 0 \iff a_{11} = 0$.

To see that this is the case, note the following.

- As is [proved here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3722044/81360), $x^TAx = 0 \iff Ax = 0$.
- For a symmetric matrix, $Ax = 0 \iff A^+x = 0$, where $A^+$ denotes the MP-pseudoinverse of $A$

Let $e_1$ denote the column vector $e_1 = (1,0,\dots,0)$. We have
$$
a_{11} = 0 \iff e_1^TAe_1 = 0 \iff Ae_1 = 0 \\
\iff A^+e_1 = 0 \iff e_1^TGe_1 = 0 \iff g_{11} = 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regarding the continuity point, I'm asking if the generalized inverse MP for this matrix is necessary continuous ($\hat{G}^+ \rightarrow {G}^+$) or not? can the condition that the main diagonal elements are all positive guarantee the continuity of the MP inverse matrix

Comment: The pseudoinverse is discontinuous whenever there is a change in matrix rank. It is continuous over sets of matrices that have constant rank.

Comment: do you mean a change in the rank for the sequence of A?.. my problem is that I have a covariance matrix that has the same structure as mentioned in the original problem (additionally $0<a_{ii}<1$), and I use the generalized inverse to get MLE for a certain parameter. To prove the asymptotic results of the estimator I need to guarantee g_{11}≠0 (this one is true now) and $g^{+}_{ij} \xrightarrow{P} g^{+}_{ij}$ does the continuity follows based on all these input or I have to assume seq of matrices (A or G?) have a constant rank? or something additional required to be proved

Comment: A sufficient condition would be that the entire sequence and its limit has the same rank. That said, I suspect that **if** the generalized inverses converge, then they must converge to the generalized inverse of the limit

Comment: Can you elaborate more the if part you have mentioned?.. Based on 
 jstor.org/stable/2099241  ,, I see the sufficient condition about that rank(A+En)=rank(A) which is the same as you mentioned implies that $G^{+}_{n}→G^{+}$.. and then  sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379577900799  shows that $\hat{G}^{+}→G^{+}$ for the MP inverse(see theorem 1) that for n x m matrices if it applies to n x n matrices, would that guarantee that the generalized inverses converge to the generalized inverse of the limit?

Comment: I don’t understand what you said after “MP inverse”

Comment: I'm asking if what you wrote " the generalized inverses converge, then they must converge to the generalized inverse of the limit" means $\hat{G}^+\rightarrow G^+$? if so the paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379577900799 proved in theorem 1 that it holds for matrices of size $n*m$.. if this is not what you mean can you elaborate more or give example why in case the entire sequence and its limit has the same rank, $\hat{g}_{ij}^{+}\rightarrow g_{ij}^{+}$ will not hold

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. That's close to what I meant. What I really mean is that if $\hat G^+ \to M$, then $M = G^+$.

Comment: 1. I think $\hat{G}^{+}\rightarrow M,$ then $M=G^+$ is granted if \hat{G}^{+} satisfices the assumptions as in corollary 1 of this paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379577900799, which should consequently imply that $\hat{g}+_{ij}\rightarrow g^+_{ij}$, right?  ...2. another case if $a_{ij}$ is uniformly consistent and continuous ($\hat{a}_{ij}\rightarrow a_{ij}$, would it imply that  $\hat{g}+_{ij}\rightarrow g^+_{ij}$ ? (bec I know that it is valid if we have the standard inverse, $\hat{a}_{ij}\rightarrow a_{ij}$ then $\hat{a}^{-1}_{ij}\rightarrow a^{-1}_{ij}$)

Comment: It is true that ${\hat G}^+ \to \hat G$ implies that ${\hat g}^+_{ij} \to \hat g_{ij}$. I'm not sure what you mean when you say that $a_{ij}$ is "uniformly consistent and continuous". It is not generally true that $\hat a_{ij} \to a_{ij}$ implies that $\hat g_{ij} \to g^+_{ij}$; this is exactly what I mean when I say that the pseudoinverse is discontinuous.

Comment: yes by "uniformly consistent and continuous" I mean $\hat{a}_{ij}\rightarrow a_{ij}$.. but do you mean $\hat{g}_{ij}^{+}\rightarrow {g}_{ij}^{+}$ or it wasn't a typo?