# Given $\nu^T G \nu=0$, how do we get $\nu \perp \operatorname{span}(G)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathscr S$ be a subspace of $\mathbb R^p$, and let G be positive semidefinite such that $\operatorname{span}(G) \subset \mathscr S$. The following statements are equivalent:

2. for all $\nu \in \mathscr S, \nu \neq 0,$ we have $\nu^T G \nu >0$;
3. $\operatorname{span}(G) = \mathscr S$.

Proof.

$3 \Rightarrow 2$. If statement 2 is not true then there exists $\nu \in \mathscr S, \nu \neq 0$, such that $\nu^T G \nu=0$. Then $\nu \perp \operatorname{span}(G)$ and statement 3 is not true.

**Question:** Given $\nu^T G \nu=0$, how do we get $\nu \perp \operatorname{span}(G)$?

I know by definition, if I want to say $\nu$ is orthogonal of a subspace $W$, then for every vector $w \in W$, we should have $\nu^T w=0$. But here I have span, which confuses me.

Comment: You should apply the positive semidefintness of $G.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Can you talk more about it?

Comment: $\text{span}(G)$ is not standard usage of the "span" operator. Do you mean the column-space of $G$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, in the textbook, the author clearly defines that he choose to use span(G) to denote the column space of G, which means the space spanned by the columns of G.  I guess this is just the usage of the span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the "span" of $G$ is its column-space.

The key fact here is that because $G$ is positive semidefinite, $v^TGv = 0$ if and only if $Gv = 0$; I present several proofs of this fact [on my post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3722044/81360).

So, the fact that $v^TGv = 0$ implies that $Gv = 0$, which is to say that $v$ is an element of the null space of $G$, which (because $G$ is a symmetric matrix) is the orthogonal complement to the column space of $G$.

Comment: Thanks! But why do you emphasize that " (because G is a symmetric matrix)"?

Comment: The key fact here is that $v^TGv = 0$ if and only if $Gv = 0$. I guess you need to say provided that $G$ is positive definite?

Comment: Can you give me a proof about "$v^TGv = 0$ if and only if $Gv = 0$" here? Of course, the other way is obvious.

Comment: In general, the null space is the orthogonal complement of the column space of $G^T$. So, it’s important that $G^T=G$.

Comment: Regarding the next two comments, see the link that I had put in my answer